# Как извлечь данные из json формата и отфильтровать по переменной из json объекта?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть столбец data,тип которого - longtext. В нём хранятся данные в формате json, пример:

```
{
"test_id":"123",
"test_data":
{
   "name":"blabla",
   "id":"7"
}
}
```

Я знаю как отфильтровать данные по `test_id`:

```
$query->whereRaw('json_extract(data, "$.test_id") = "' . $testId . '"');
```

А как отфильтровать по test_data[id]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query->whereRaw('data->"$.test_data.id" = :id', ['id' => $testId]);
```

так должно заработать

Comment: спасибо, работает. А можешь подсказать, как сделать, если $testId будет массивом чисел? что-то наподобии этого ->whereIn('test_id', $testId)

Comment: `$query->whereRaw('data->"$.test_data.id" IN :ids', ['ids' => $testIdList]);`

попробуй так

Comment: Syntax error or access violation